# ASP.NET Core with WebSockets - WebSocket handshake never occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I am very new to C# programming, having previously only worked with Java. This project I am building should be very straightforward - we have a web page with a selection of foreign currency pairs. The element chosen is sent to the server, which responds with a hardcoded value of their exchange rate. The requirement is that both actions are implemented through the use of WebSockets. Here is the JS code on my page:

```
var protocol;
var wsUri;
var socket;

window.onload = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();



    protocol = location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss:" : "ws:";
    wsUri = protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    socket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

    socket.onopen = e => {
        console.log("socket opened", e);
    };

    document.getElementById("currencypair").onchange = function()
    {
        var selector = document.getElementById("currencypair");
        var text = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].text;
        socket.send(text);
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
        var receivedMessage = evt.data;
        document.getElementById("output").html(receivedMessage);
    };


};
```

Here is a snippet of the Startup.cs class Configure method:

```
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketMiddleware>();
```

And here is the middleware class to process requests.

```
public class WebSocketMiddleware
{

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public WebSocketMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
            return;
        }

        var ct = context.RequestAborted;
        using (var socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var stringReceived = await ReceiveStringAsync(socket, ct);

                if (CurrencyPairCollection.CurrencyPairs.TryGetValue(stringReceived, out var value))
                {
                    await SendStringAsync(socket, value.ToString(), ct);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected value");
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
            }
        }

    }

    private static async Task<string> ReceiveStringAsync(WebSocket socket, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result;
            do
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, ct);
                ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
            }
            while (!result.EndOfMessage);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            if (result.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Text || result.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected message");
            }

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Task SendStringAsync(WebSocket socket, string data, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        return socket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, ct);
    }

}
```

Please mind I was working with the following example which contains mistakes listed by people in the comment section. I did my best to resolve them, however due to my limited experience, that may be where the fault lies.

https://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/Using-Web-Sockets-with-ASP-NET-Core

Basically, upon running the app the browser console immediately reports this:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:51017/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: It’s not an answer per se but maybe you should consider using SignalR, it would ease your life ;-) however I see that you’re using .Net Core ans SignalR is only available for .NET Core 2.1 so you would have to use nightly build until end of the year (2.1-preview1)

Comment: Yeah, I probably would have tried that out. Thing is, the requirement is WebSockets. Thanks though.

Comment: I don’t get it. SignalR is using web socket.

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 is a requirement as well:) This is a project received after a job interview.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm going to need to turn this in today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to answer my own question. So in Startup.cs of which I provided only a snippet, a call to app.UseMvc() is made right before the lines I have already shared. This is generated by the default template. The trick was to move this call to below the following:

```
    app.UseWebSockets();
    app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketMiddleware>();
```

as otherwise the request pipeline is disrupted.

This will allow our socket to open, however without changing the following line in async Task ReceiveStringAsync(...)

```
var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>();
```

to

```
var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[8192]);
```

it will still close prematurely. Next, just needed to correct JS syntax error. Changed

```
document.getElementById("output").html(receivedMessage);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("output").value = receivedMessage;
```

That's it, it works.